# How to merge multiple meshes into one (animated)

Tags: mesh, texturing, armature

I have recently bought a 3D model online that unfortunately is split into 3 meshes and textures. And, I cannot use it with my game engine because it only accepts a single skinned mesh and a single texture *diffuse*.

I cannot afford to pay an artist to fix this for me so I was hoping I could do it myself but my modelling knowledge is very limited.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to merge the 3 meshes into one while keeping the animation? (its a fairy where the wand/wing/body is separated)
2. For the texture, can I merge all the UV so I can merge the textures in Photoshop? (each mesh wand/wing/body has a texture file)

[image]

Comment: I tried merging it by selecting the 3 objects and joining but unfortunately and shared material when merged the wings texture goes away.

Comment: Also tried texture atlas but it kept giving me an error about `tex.name`

Comment: Could you add pictures about the textures and a screenshot from the whole window?